# Unable to extract h264 video from MKV

Tags: video, ffmpeg, h.264

I'm asking this here because I was unable to find a better StackExchange site for it. Correct me if I'm wrong.

The problem I'm facing is with a particular MKV file. It has a video stream (h264) that I'm trying to extract. The problem is that mkvmerge, mkvextract, and ffmpeg seem to skip over a section of the video. They skip over the exact same section. I know the file isn't corrupted because I'm able to play it just fine. I've tried various options, re-encoding and copying the stream with ffmpeg, but even copying the stream results in the output skipping over the section of video. I've been stuck with this for quite a while now. Any solution or suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Well apparently, the ffdshow decoder can decode it properly. How do I use the system ffdshow decoder with ffmpeg?

Comment: That's bizarre, as ffdshow uses an old version of ffmpeg (2012) to decode. Run the ffmpeg command with `-v 40` and show the console output.

Comment: Well, I put together a little program that uses the system DirectShow codec to decode the video stream and then encode it using "Lagarith Lossless Codec". So far, it's working nicely, I'm able to get all of the video. I just have to see if ffmpeg can read "Lagarith".